# Do low cost ETFs or mutual funds really do well for an investor?

Tags: united-states, etf, mutual-funds, rate-of-return, expense-ratio

There are many [ETFs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange-traded_fund), [Mutual Funds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_fund) and [Unit Trusts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_investment_trust) in the market. Some ETFs advertise a low [Expense Ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expense_ratio) and [Total Expense Ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_expense_ratio).

There are many examples:

IVV, VOO and SPY for S&P 500

VNQ, RWR and SCHH for REITs

I would like to find a calculation, empirical evidence, real data that shows that $10k invested on a date (suppose January 2, 2010) would have been so many dollars  in one ETF vs another or any other date, to know the net benefit to the investor.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the individual ETF/fund websites where all this historical data is available and _reconstructing_ the calculations yourself?

Comment: Not an answer, but you're going to find some low-fee funds that underperform the market and some high-fee funds that outperform the market. I would not expect to find a strong correlation between the fee level and the performance of a fund.

Comment: -1. There are tools to measure the performance of stocks and ETFs. Just compare two ETFs following the same index (say, VOO vs SPY) over a long period of time and you'll see the difference. You can also find the expected difference in costs (using your $10k investment) by looking at the summary prospectuses of the two funds. Not sure what the point of this question is.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a DRIP calculator that allows you to compare the performance of ETFs and stocks with and without dividend reinvestment.  You have to do them one at a time:

- https://www.dividendchannel.com/drip-returns-calculator/

There are lots of screeners available.  For example,  you can look up various ETF  performance stats at:

- https://etfdb.com/etfs/

Finviz offers a variety of screeners:

- https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=141

For closed end funds:

- https://www.cefconnect.com/closed-end-funds-screener

For  mutual funds, you can find various total return stats at the  web sites of each issuer (Vanguard, Fidelity, etc.).

"The truth is out there"